# Can't access my index.html (via Apache) from other computer (LAN nor Internet)? Please help

Tags: windows, apache, http

lets make it simple to answer.

I installed Apache 2.2. Now when I do 127.0.0.1 in Firefox, I get the "It works" page. When I do 10.0.1.10 (my servers internal IP) on another PC on the SAME network, I won't get anything :-(. I forwarded port 80 on my router and made sure Firewall doesn't block Apache. If I type my external IP:80 I still can't get into my "index.html". My settings (more less default)

```
Network Domain: localhost
Server Name: localhost
```

I also got a FTP via FileZilla running on that PC. It works perfectly, even over Internet. I have also set up a DynDns hostname. If I do ftp://mydyndns.hostname.com I get to my ftp server.

What am I missing? Some more Windows setup?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What happens when you go to 10.0.1.10 on the machine on which you installed Apache?

Comment: Based on that I'd still suspect the firewall.

Comment: Turned firewall off - no success, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Linux on my computer and found all servers run better on it :) Thanks everyone...